# How can i fasten java text file search with binarysearch?

Tags: java, arrays, character-encoding, binary-search

I am trying to make a small app which makes searches in text files and recognise the language used in it(firstly between english and turkish). For this purpose i am searching the byte appearance of letter "k". According to some researches this letter is widely used in turkish and very less used in english and have same byte number. However the problem is it takes around 20 seconds (or maybe a little more with i7 7700hq comp) to find the appearance of letter k in a text of 110k letters with my code, so it is a big problem for me as i am planning to run this code over 1k text files. Should i make the search with another method of java or is this the fastest way it can be?

Thanks in advance

My code is:

```
package deneme;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

public class deneme {
    public static int howmany =0;
    public static double ratio;
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException{

        File file = new File("c:\\tr1.srt");
          byte[] bytesArray = new byte[(int) file.length()]; 

          FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
          fis.read(bytesArray); //read file into bytes[]
          fis.close();
          byte searchVal = 107; // 'k' letter in byte code

          for(byte textbytes:bytesArray){
              Arrays.sort(bytesArray);
              int retVal = Arrays.binarySearch(bytesArray,0,bytesArray.length,searchVal);
              if(retVal >-1){
                  bytesArray[retVal]=0;
                  howmany++;
              }
          }
          System.out.println("Character \"k\" appears " + howmany +" times in the text");
          ratio = (double)howmany/(double)bytesArray.length;
          System.out.println("How many: "+howmany);
          System.out.println("Length: "+bytesArray.length);
          System.out.println("Ratio: "+ratio);
          if(ratio<0.01){
              System.out.println("Text file is probably not turkish");
          }else{
              System.out.println("Text file is probably turkish");
          }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorting will visit every byte already, so you shouldn't need to sort but just visit every byte once.

You can actually count all bytes' frequencies if you do:

```
int[] freqs = new int[256];
for(byte b: bytearray)
   freqs[b&0x0ff]++;
```

then just lookup the byte you like, as in freqs['k']+freqs['K'].

Also, you could just open a bufferedinputstream over the fileinputstream, and avoid the huge byte[], just iterate over bufferedinputstream.read() (which is an int 0..255) and stop when -1.

Comment: Since the OP is only interested in `k` or `K`, it is enough to count only these characters, No needed counting other characters. Also it's not `byte`s but `char`s.

Comment: It's the OP to decide if this has a single byte charset or not. But 'k' and 'K' are single bytes in latin-x, and utf8. He's not trying to read UTF16 obviously. So the reader is not helping but slowing things down. Meanwhile, counting all frequencies that thightly will be fully pipelined in cpu instruction prefetch and cost nearly nothing, operating on 4 cache lines (4 x 64 bytes) only. Plus, he's equipped to check other letters now at no cost.

Comment: You are right about bytes vs. characters. Still, I won't count all characters if this is not needed.

Answer (score 1):

Sorting is a costly operation. And you are sorting your array for every character, which is inefficient. Instead, you could just go sequentially through all the characters once and if that particular character is 'k', then just increment the counter. Here is a sample code

```
for(byte textBytes: bytesArray) {
    if(textBytes == searchVal) {
        howmany++;
    }
}
```

use this for loop instead of yours. You should get the results much faster.

Answer (score 1):

First, if you work with letters, use a `Reader`, not `InputStream`:

```
Reader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
```

Next, the way you have implemented counting the letter 'k' is... how should I put it... very creative. You binary-search for 'k' many times as long as it is found. While this works, it is very far from optimal. I think it's `O(n*log n)` whereas it is easily solveable in `O(n)` with one pass through read characters. Something along the lines:

```
private static final char CHAR_k = 'k';
// ...
int count_k = 0;
int r;
while ((r = reader.read()) != -1) {
    char ch = (char) r;
    if (ch == CHAR_k) {
        count_k++
    }
}
```

Comment: I didn't prefer to read characters as for next step i am planning to find out if the text is ansii(latin-5) or utf-8. By reading byte values i can understand that if the text is ansii or utf-8 after finding out its language. For example turkish character "ı" is 0xfd in ansii table but it doesnt exist in utf-8 (i guess it is 0x0131 at unicode table) So if i check out character "ı" as char i guess it will showup in both ansii and utf-8 but wont show up as byte in both.